# Character Sets in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unicode

I am using VS2010 and I have these in my code:

```
::MessageBox(0, "Init FAILED", 0, 0);
```

When I compiled the project, I got the error that cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [25]' to 'LPCWSTR'. I searched the problem on the Internet, people told me to change the 'character sets' option in my project settings from 'Unicode' to 'Not Set'. But it does not work. When I run these codes:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    printf("unicode");
#else
    printf("others");
#endif
```

I get the same answer "unicode" no matter what option I have chosen. What should I do to handle the problem?

Comment: Change `"Init FAILED"` to `L"Init FAILED"`

Comment: That would surely work, but I think there is some problem about my vs2010. And there are lots of strings in my code, it is not a good idea to change them all.

Comment: Change it to multibyte character set, as it's probably defaulting to unicode.

Comment: Why are you not using the _T() or TEXT() macro for string?  For Visual C++, and especially for Windows programs, strings literals used in API calls will either be "wide" or ANSI.  To make sure your app builds correctly regardless of the character set setting, use the _T() macro: `_T("My String")` instead of just `"My String"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your original question, you didn't need to change the character set.  The solution is to use the _T() macro that is defined in tchar.h.

```
::MessageBox(0, _T("Init Failed"), 0, 0);
```

The _T() macro will either specify a wide string by appending an "L" onto the string, or an ANSI string by leaving the string alone.

You should change the character set *only* if you truly want to use the character set you're changing to.  You don't change the character set just because your code doesn't compile.

Comment: I prefer using `L"Init Failed"`. `_T()` is only useful in case you're going to compile in both ANSI and Unicode, and the only reason for that would be to support Win9x, which is long irrelevant.

Comment: @Jonathan: The character set option and OS being targeted are two separate items.  The character set option is still available in VS 2013, and that compiler does not target Win9x in any way.

Comment: The `_T()` macro is only useful in old/legacy code, never in development of new code. Too bad that Win32 never had (and never will have) support for UTF-8 encoded narrow strings, then the `_T()` macro and all the `L""` nonsense would die off.

Comment: FYI `_T()` is for C runtime code, and is based on the `_UNICODE` define. The Win32 equivalent is `TEXT()`, which is based on the `UNICODE` define. Different frameworks, different defines, different macros, similar purposes.  You should not mix them.  Use C macros for C code, and Win32 macros for Win32 code, eg: `::MessageBox(0, TEXT("Init Failed"), 0, 0);`